# XSD and element existence requirement, or other options

Tags: xsd, xml-validation

At the XSD level, can I define an element requirement based on presence of another element in the document?

For example, I want to require the element `<firstname />` be provided whenever the `<id />` element is also present, otherwise first name is optional.

If this cannot be enforced at the XSD level, then should I make both elements optional and enforce the requirement through a different level of checking?

Options welcome.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with XSD (like pmartin said), but it can be done with a DTD. Let me know if you are interested and I'll post an example.

Comment: @DevNull: Sure, go ahead and post an example of DTD because my question title asks for options, and that kind of information is useful to future visitors. I amended the question text with "Options welcome" to reinforce the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be enforced at the XSD level.

Making both elements optional and enforcing the requirement at a different level in the application architecture sounds like a good option to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of this being done in a DTD. (Note: The test instances were validated using oXygen XML Editor (which is using Xerces).)

**DTD (test.dtd)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT user ((firstname?|(firstname,id)),lastname)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
```

Here are some example XML instances (valid and invalid):

**Valid**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE user SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<user>
  <firstname/>
  <id/>
  <lastname/>
</user>
```

**Invalid**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE user SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<user>
  <id/>
  <lastname/>
</user>
```

**Valid**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE user SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<user>
  <firstname/>
  <lastname/>
</user>
```